# Given a linear function and a normal (and invertiable) matrix. Prove the linear function to be normal

Tags: linear-algebra

*side note: I am translating the question from a different language the best i can*

The question reads:
Let $M \in M^C_{nxn}$ be invertible. $S: M_{nxn}^C \rightarrow M_{nxn}^C$  is defined as $S(X) = XM^{-1}$. Given $M$ to be a normal matrix, prove $S$ to be normal as well.

My friends and I spent forever trying to solve this with no luck, any help will be appreciated

Comment: What is your definition of a normal linear application?

Comment: @Miguel, not sure what is the right word in English, but the best way I can define it is when linear transformation's representative matrix is normal

Comment: But what does "normal" mean in the context of a matrix or any linear transformation?

Comment: @PatrickAbraham, [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) that can explain it much better than me

Comment: A matrix $n \times n$ is an application from $\mathbb R^n$ (or $\mathbb C^n$) to itself, which your application is not.

Comment: To start, have in mind the correct definitions: $S$ is normal [if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator) $S$ commute with $S^*$, the unique linear map $\textsf M_{n \times n}(\mathbb C) \to \textsf M_{n \times n}(\mathbb C)$ such that $\langle S(X),Y \rangle = \langle X,S^*(Y) \rangle$ for all $X$ and $Y$ in $\textsf M_{n \times n}(\mathbb C)$, where $\langle ,\rangle$ is the usual dot-product, that is, if $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{ij})$ are $n \times n$ complex matrices, then $\langle A,B \rangle = \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}\overline{b_{ij}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is
$$
\langle X,Y\rangle=trace(Y^\ast X).
$$
If $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $S(X):= XA$, then $S^\ast(X)=XA^\ast $, since
$$
\langle S(X),Y\rangle = \langle XA,Y\rangle = trace(Y^\ast XA) = trace(AY^\ast X) = 
trace((YA^\ast)^\ast X) = \langle X,YA^\ast\rangle.
$$
If $A$ is normal (i.e. $AA^\ast=A^\ast A$), then for each $X \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ we have
$$
S(S^*(X))= S(XA^\ast)=XA^\ast A= XA A^\ast = S^\ast(XA)=S^\ast(S(X)).
$$
Thus $S$ is normal. If $M$ is invertible and normal then $M^{-1}$ is normal.
I think that invertibility is not an issue.